# how to load previously made leader

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

Age of wonders 3 has a ton of customization options for the leader. And in the previous version I was always able to save it and load my previously saved customization.

There is a checkbox to save the customized leader, but I can't find the option to load that saved leader.

Answer (score 2):

Just found a tab 'custom' at the right next to the 'Library' tab with all the pre-made leaders. It did include leaders I made previously, just not the last one, for some reason...

Anyway clicking on the leader item in that list loads it.